# Server Sent Events with Hybrid Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hybrid-mobile-app, ecmascript-5

I'm working on a hybrid app that is based on Angular 1.5.  In part of the app now, the client wants a messaging system for the admin of a group to be able to message the normal worker/user.  I want to check and see if this is done, would server sent events be the solution? If so, do I continue to let it  run  as the user has the app open? How does this affect performance?

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming authentication would need to be performed against users in order to differentiate between admin and worker accounts.

Have Angular send AJAX calls to your server, which will check the users' authentication status before the client-side view is rendered.

You should research the `resolve` property in Angular in order to implement this type of solution.

Comment: I'll check out resolve.  But as far as ajax, that  is a solution, but as far as I know, Server sent events establish the connection and keep it open correct? where Ajax calls actually do all the work, and then close it.

Comment: Fundamentally AJAX polls the server for new data and gets a response between intervals and it works over HTTP. In HTTP, it opens a connection on request and closes on response, so you would be correct in saying the connection is not kept open. I am not familiar with your use case but an AJAX implementation would work if you wanted to check the for authentication and Angular provides AJAX functions.

Comment: If you wish to keep an open connection between a client application and a server you could look into the WebSockets protocol.

Comment: Sadly that is not an option. Most hosts do not offer socket servers in my experience. I  just know SSE makes the initial connection and keeps it open. I just want to know if it is efficient. Is it something I could access using a worker?

Comment: HTTP keep-alive isn't reliable enough for a persistent connection. An HTTP request header is around 200 bytes in size and it could be up to 2KB for the full request. This adds much latency when sending messages back and forth. WebSockets will always win in this regard because the messages are much smaller in size and data is streamed end-to-end with full duplex.

Comment: Cnic, is there a place where I can make a socket server without breaking the bank?

Comment: @CalebPrenger You could run a Socket server on a Raspberry Pi or look for a free VPS online.

Comment: what If i run a web worker using blobs.  How efficient would it be to keep that worker alive and set an interval maybe once every 2 minutes to check for messages?